# Accumulated summing of java object properties

Tags: java, arraylist, stream, java-stream

I have this java List of objects

```
List<Stats> myStats = [
    {id:3, numberOfTags:60, latestDateTime:2022-12-08T15:00:00},
    {id:1, numberOfTags:50, latestDateTime:2022-12-08T14:00:00},
    {id:1, numberOfTags:10, latestDateTime:2022-12-08T10:00:00},
    {id:1, numberOfTags:15, latestDateTime:2022-12-08T16:00:00},
    {id:2, numberOfTags:20, latestDateTime:2022-12-08T11:00:00},
    {id:3, numberOfTags:30, latestDateTime:2022-12-08T12:00:00},
    {id:2, numberOfTags:200,latestDateTime:2022-12-09T13:00:00},
    {id:2, numberOfTags:40, latestDateTime:2022-12-08T13:00:00}
]
```

I need to sum all `numberOfTags` on each `LocalDateTime` of the `latestDateTime` property.

When only 1 id has value for `numberOfTags` for a specific `latestDateTime` we add the previous value of `numberOfTags` from previous `latestDateTime`.

For example on 2022-12-08T11:00:00 Total `numerOfTags` should be 30 because `id`:2 has `numberOfTags`: 20 and its only value for that `LocalDateTime` so we repeat the `numberOfTags` for 2022-12-08T10:00:00 which was 10 for `id`:1 making total `numberOfTags` for 2022-12-08T11:00:00 30 because 10 + 20. So the rule is sum each row where 0 replace with previous value Image below explains it better

[image]

Here is my code

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Stats> myStats = List.of(
                new Stats(1, 10, LocalDateTime.parse("2022-12-08T10:00:00")),
                new Stats(2, 20, LocalDateTime.parse("2022-12-08T11:00:00")),
                new Stats(3, 30, LocalDateTime.parse("2022-12-08T12:00:00")),
                new Stats(2, 40, LocalDateTime.parse("2022-12-08T13:00:00")),
                new Stats(1, 50, LocalDateTime.parse("2022-12-08T14:00:00")),
                new Stats(3, 60, LocalDateTime.parse("2022-12-08T15:00:00")),
                new Stats(1, 15, LocalDateTime.parse("2022-12-08T16:00:00")),
                new Stats(2, 200, LocalDateTime.parse("2022-12-09T13:00:00")) 
        );

        List<Stats> sortedStats = myStats.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Stats::getLatestDateTime))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
        Map<LocalDateTime, Integer> tagCountByDateTime = new HashMap<>();
        int previousTagCount = 0;

        for (Stats stats : sortedStats) {
            LocalDateTime dateTime =stats.getLatestDateTime();
            int tagCount = stats.getNumberOfTags();

            if (tagCountByDateTime.containsKey(dateTime)) {
                tagCountByDateTime.put(dateTime, tagCountByDateTime.get(dateTime) + tagCount);
            } else {
                tagCountByDateTime.put(dateTime, previousTagCount + tagCount);
            }

            previousTagCount += tagCount;
        }

        // Then you can iterate over the map to get the sum of tag counts by date time
        for (Map.Entry<LocalDateTime, Integer> entry : tagCountByDateTime.entrySet()) {
            LocalDateTime dateTime = entry.getKey();
            int tagCount = entry.getValue();

            System.out.println(dateTime + ": " + tagCount);
        }
    }
}
    
class Stats {
    private int id;
    private int numberOfTags;
    private LocalDateTime latestDateTime;

    public Stats(int id, int numberOfTags, LocalDateTime latestDateTime) {
        this.id = id;
        this.numberOfTags = numberOfTags;
        this.latestDateTime = latestDateTime;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getNumberOfTags() {
        return numberOfTags;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getLatestDateTime() {
        return latestDateTime;
    }
}
```

result for numOfTagsByDateTime should be

```
{
    2022-12-08T10:00:00 = 10,
    2022-12-08T11:00:00 = 30,
    2022-12-08T12:00:00 = 60,
    2022-12-08T13:00:00 = 80,
    2022-12-08T14:00:00 = 120,
    2022-12-08T15:00:00 = 150,
    2022-12-08T16:00:00 = 115,
    2022-12-09T13:00:00 = 275
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like you need `Collectors.groupingBy`

Comment: @g00se To group by the latestDateTime?

Comment: Did you print and inspect the map `numOfTagsByDateTime`?  You might want to show what that map is supposed to look like?  Because I don't see how you can get `115` from the results which look are `2022-12-09T13:00=200,  2022-12-08T15:00=60,
2022-12-08T16:00=15`

Comment: @WJS so you add values in each imaginary row like i have in the image. You dont convert the LocalDateTiem to LocalDate but when you have LocalDateTimes with same Date ignoring the Time part you select the LocalDateTime with the latest time. Add not at each LocalDateTime when you have just 1 id with a non zero value you add it to previous values of the other 2 id's

Comment: Ok, but what is that map supposed to look like with the current data?  Can you edit your question and show it because that is all you are using to construct the final map.

Comment: @WJS which map are you refering to

Comment: numOfTagsByDateTime

Comment: Made changes to the question

Comment: Okay.  Those values are not in `numOfTagsByDateTime`.  The values in that map are the ones I highlighted in my comment.

Comment: That shouldn't be the output it should be what i added in the question.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, can you provide us with a [mre] or is the compilation error your problem?

Comment: @cyberbrain i added a compiling code

Comment: please rename your private `Object` class to prevent further confusion.

Comment: In your example, all `latestDateTime` entries are unique, so the rule of "adding the previous value" (when sorted by `latestDateTime`) applies to all entries and so your expected result doesn't match the rule you gave us. Please refine either the expected result or the rule.

Comment: Made the changes @cyberbrain

Comment: So what I understand now is that you want to build some kind of pivot table and then process it: the `latestDateTime` goes as rows, the `id` as columns and the `numberOfTags` is the value. For each row you take the values in the missing columns from the previous row. The result should be for each date the sum of the three value columns. Is this correct?

Comment: If my previous assumptions are correct: why does your expected result contain 200 for 2022-12-09T13:00 ? (The spreadsheet screenshot shows 275 there.) Do the initial values start at 0 for a new day ?

Comment: You are correct with your explanantion. Oh sorry the expected result should be 275 not 200. It can start with 0 or non 0 value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the clarified requirements I found a solution that brings the expected result:

```java
package examples.stackoverflow.q75042726;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Q75042726 {

  private record Stats(Integer id, Integer numberOfTags, LocalDateTime latestDateTime) {
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Stats> statistics = List.of(new Stats(3, 60, LocalDateTime.of(2022, 12, 8, 15, 0, 0)), new Stats(1, 50, LocalDateTime.of(2022, 12, 8, 14, 0, 0)), new Stats(1, 10, LocalDateTime.of(2022, 12, 8, 10, 0, 0)), new Stats(1, 15, LocalDateTime.of(2022, 12, 8, 16, 0, 0)), new Stats(2, 20, LocalDateTime.of(2022, 12, 8, 11, 0, 0)), new Stats(3, 30, LocalDateTime.of(2022, 12, 8, 12, 0, 0)), new Stats(2, 200, LocalDateTime.of(2022, 12, 9, 13, 0, 0)), new Stats(2, 40, LocalDateTime.of(2022, 12, 8, 13, 0, 0)));
    System.out.println(summarize(statistics));
  }

  private static Map<LocalDateTime, Integer> summarize(List<Stats> items) {
    if (items.size() == 0) {
      return Collections.emptyMap();
    }
    List<Stats> workList = new ArrayList<>(items);
    workList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Stats::latestDateTime));

    int maxId = workList.stream().mapToInt(Stats::id).max().orElse(0);
    int[] values = new int[maxId];
    Arrays.fill(values, 0);

    Map<LocalDateTime, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();

    LocalDateTime previous = workList.get(0).latestDateTime;
    for (Stats current : workList) {
      if (!previous.equals(current.latestDateTime)) {
        result.put(previous, Arrays.stream(values).sum());
      }
      previous = current.latestDateTime;

      int index = current.id - 1;
      values[index] = current.numberOfTags;
    }
    result.put(previous, Arrays.stream(values).sum());
    return result;
  }
}
```

Please note that I used a Java record instead of your class `Stats` here for the sake of brevity and also because it's exactly meant for that use. Works since Java 14.

Comment: I get this illegal identifier used error on the record Stats on line 10

Comment: Probably you use an older version of Java than Java 14 - you still can rewrite my code to use your `Stats` class instead: either you will replace the references to `id`, `numberOfTags` and `latestDateTime` with their respective getters, or you make `Stats` a inner `private static class` so you can access the fields directly. But I didn't check if all the used methods also exist for the Java version you use (because I don't know the version). If possible I would recommend that you update Java to version 17, the latest long term supported version.

Comment: Great done, the current issue I have is Map<LocalDateTime, Integer> summarize(List<Stats> items) I get an error like "Expression expected, create local variable 'Stats' "

Comment: which of the suggested solutions did you choose? (Update Java, make Stats an inner private static class or use the getters)

Comment: Updated Java using 17

Comment: I updated the answer to contain a completely runnable example - if you get any errors there, more details on the error would be helpful, but be prepared that we ask you to write another question, depending on the error ;)

Comment: This worked gave the correct output

Comment: if the id is not an integer but a uuid do i count rather tthan mapToInt here ""int maxId = workList.stream().mapToInt(Stats::id).max().orElse(0)"'

Comment: In that case you have to create a map first, which UUID maps to which column index - and then count the size of the map for the number of colums. Keep in mind that Java doesn't provide associative arrays like PHP, but you can only specify an index inside the `[]`

Comment: Okay cool will do that